# Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid - Add user to database

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim FName As String = txtFName.Text
Dim LName As String = txtLName.Text
Dim ADD1 As String = txtADD1.Text
Dim ADD2 As String = txtADD2.Text
Dim ADDC As String = txtADDCITY.Text
Dim ADDPC As String = txtADDPC.Text
Dim TEL As String = txtTel.Text
Dim EMAIL As String = txtEmail.Text
If FName = "" Or LName = "" Or ADD1 = "" Or ADD2 = "" Or ADDC = "" Or ADDPC = "" Or TEL = "" Or EMAIL = "" = "" Then
    MsgBox("You haven't entered data into each field, double check and try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
Else
    connString = provider & datafile
    con.ConnectionString = connString
    con.Open()
    sqlstatement = "INSERT INTO CustomerInfo(FirstName, LastName, addressLine1, addressLine2, City, Postcode, PhoneNum, EmailAddress, ) VALUES ('" & FName & "','" & LName & "','" & ADD1 & "','" & ADD2 & "','" & ADDC & "','" & ADDPC & "','" & TEL & "','" & EMAIL & "',' )"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstatement, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "ADDNew")
    con.Close()
    MsgBox(FName & " " & LName & " has now been added to the database.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Me.Close()
End If
```

I need help. I am trying to make this system to add a user to a database, however when I try to validate the information entered it comes up with this error `Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid`.

Answer (score 0):

`EMAIL = "" = ""` this part is incorrect. Change it to `EMAIL = ""`

Also I change your query string...

`"INSERT INTO CustomerInfo(FirstName, LastName, addressLine1, addressLine2, City, Postcode, PhoneNum, EmailAddress) VALUES ('" & FName & "','" & LName & "','" & ADD1 & "','" & ADD2 & "','" & ADDC & "','" & ADDPC & "','" & TEL & "','" & EMAIL & "')"`

You have an extra comma in this part: `...EmailAddress,` and also in this part: `...EMAIL & "','`. Remove those. I also suggest using `Stored Procedures` because your database will be vulnerable with `SQL Injections` using concatenated queries.